# List of all Shared Links in the SharePoint Online tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, share, links

Is it possible to generate a list of all Shared links in a Tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the sharing auditing in the audit log to find all Shared Links in the SharePoint Online tenant.

Use sharing auditing in the audit log for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-sharing-auditing?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: This audit report shows only 3 month data and it shows the links which were deleted also. Is there any Powershell script using which i can take a report of shared links which are currently active?