# How can i see all the permissions from users into a especific sharepoint website

Tags: external-users, authorization

I am new to SharePoint.  How can I see all the permissions for users of a specific SharePoint site?, some users are seeing more than they are supposed to see.

Is there an interface where I can list all permissions or a script?

Now I only can see one by one, I would like to see all users permissions at once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Wanted to know exactly what everyone had access to.
For particular doc libraries, files, lists, etc., open permissions for that content and click Check Permissions... you can enter a group or person's name.
But, I wanted a master list.  Here's what I did.

1. In PowerBI, create a new blank query and connect to the ODATA source, will look something like this:
   **= OData.Feed("https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE/_api/Web/SiteGroups/", null, [Implementation="2.0"])**  (This will give a listing of all the groups, and share links)
2. Filter the list to a specific group title (make sure you filter on the Title of the group/link), not just the ID#.  Looks like this: **= Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Title] = "xxx"))**  I did this for each group I was interested in.
3. Expand the Users column **= Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Title] = "xxx"))**

You now have a listing of the members for that group.  To get a master list:

4. Combine tables into one master list **= Table.Combine({#"Group 1", #"Group 2",#"Group 3"})**
5. Expand the Group column **= Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Groups", {"Title"}, {"Group"})**

Now you have a single list of all users, and what group they belong to.  If familiar with the permissions of the group you now know who can do what.  If not, go to Site Permission using the gear icon, and click Advanced Permission Settings, or modify this URL **https://[COMPANY].sharepoint.com/sites/[SITE]/_layouts/15/user.aspx**

Unfortunately, for the Sharing Links, it does not show what the content is, only the Content ID.  To get the Content ID of a list, library, go o the item's settings, and take the last part of the URL, for example **https://[COMPANY].sharepoint.com/sites/[SITES]/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=[Content ID]**

#### External Users

If you want to see what has been shared with external users via links, this document will walk you through it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/audit-log-sharing?view=o365-worldwide#how-to-identify-resources-shared-with-external-users which was answered in a different question: [List of all Shared Links in the SharePoint Online tenant?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280713/list-of-all-shared-links-in-the-sharepoint-online-tenant)